# desktopCapture issue (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have tried to create an extension for chrome that captures the screen. But I found an issue (in my opinion). `chooseDesktopMedia` shows the dialogue for choosing the screen and hides it immediately.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "desktopCapture",
  "description": "User testing application",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture"
  ]
}
```

popup.js

```
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
      ["screen", "window"],
      function(id) {
        console.log("id",id);
      });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Desktop capture</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The popup automatically closes so I guess you'll need to make the request in an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Comment: Why are you using a popup? Based on what you've shown (which might be minimized for presentation here), you only have one button in your popup. You are asking the user to click the `browser_action` button and then click a second time in your popup. That is, generally, bad UX design. If you only have one choice in your popup (and no further information), then the browser action button should just perform the action, without forcing the user to click on yet another button. You can set the button's `title` to give the user a tooltip which states what will happen when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thx, but it's not the final design. There is a first step to create extension. Also, thx to @wOxxOm for the suggestion, it's helps, but I still don't understand why I have to use background script in this case